# x-forwarded-for not working to get client ip

Tags: node.js, nginx

I try to get `ip` in `node.js - nginx` site configuration:

```
var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress
```

My nginx settings:

```
location / {
        proxy_pass    http://127.0.0.1:3086/;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    }
```

Instead of `ip` address of client I got: `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0`

Comment: are you using express? req.ip is available in expressjs.

Comment: try adding `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;`

Comment: express: app.set('trust proxy', true); then get ip via req.ip

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at the ip for X-Forwarded-For but you are setting the header X-Real-IP.

So either you set X-Forward-For in nginx or you look at X-Real-IP in your node.js configuration/application.